# Bootsrap.css isn't loaded to pdf generated with PuppeteerSharp

Tags: css, .net-core, bootstrap-4, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I'm trying to generate a pdf with PuppeteerSharp, and i can't find a way to successfully load bootstrap css for the page's grid.
code:

```
    using (Browser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options)){
    using (Page page = await browser.NewPageAsync()){
        await page.SetContentAsync(someHtmlContent);
        AddTagOptions bootstrapCSS = new AddTagOptions() {Path=pathToBootsrapCss};
        AddTagOptions otherCSS = new AddTagOptions() {Path=pathToOtherCSSThatLoadedFine};
        await page.AddStyleTagAsync(bootstrapCSS);
        await page.AddStyleTagAsync(otherCSS);
        await page.GetContentAsync();
        await page.PdfAsync(pathToFile, pdfOpts);
}}
```

The other css is loading fine but the bootstrap is not affecting any of my grid (using classes col-sm-x).
As I was trying to debug this, apparently when I was using headless = false, saw that in the html the bootstrap actually is loaded fine.

Hope that someone seen this before and can help me.
Thanks, and sorry for my lousy english...

Comment: Remember that the PDF emulates a print not a screenshot.

Comment: @hardkoded Thanks for the answer. 
Can you suggest a way for me to get the desired pdf with the loaded bootstrap css? Is your library even support that?

Comment: @hardkoded is the library supports .NET Core v.3 ?

Comment: Puppeteer relies on the print to PDF feature from Chrome. You should try to see how your page looks when you try to print it. You might need to add some media print CSS. It does support .NET Core 3